# How to manipulate LDAP using JNDI on websphere?

Tags: ldap, websphere, jndi

I am facing a problem with an LDAP operation. I want to dynamically add a member to an LDAP group when selected by the user from GUI / browser. I paste the code below which works perfectly well when I run it in a Test class (using `com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory`). But, when I package it in my build, deploy on websphere app server 7.0 (using `com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory`), and invoke this method according to user's selection, then I get the error below. I wonder what's wrong I am doing. Doesn't WAS provide implementation of ldap connection factory? I also tried deploying on WAS with the sun's ldap which otherwise works on the Test class, but I am getting the same exception as below. I'd appreciate if anybody can give a clue.

> Problem adding member: javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - 00000561: SvcErr: DSID-031A120C, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0

```
My Code:

public class LDAPManager
{
    String GROUPS_OU =  "cn=users,dc=mit,dc=hq,dc=com";

    public Boolean addMember(String user, String group)
    {

        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        String adminName = "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=mit,DC=hq,DC=com";
        String adminPassword = "asdfasdf21Q";
        String ldapURL = "ldap://mybox451Dev.mit.hq.com:389";
        String userName = "CN="+user+",CN=Users,DC=mit,DC=hq,DC=com";
        String groupName = "CN="+group+",CN=Users,DC=mit,DC=hq,DC=com";


        //env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");

        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");

        //set security credentials, note using simple cleartext authentication
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,"simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,adminName);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,adminPassword);

        //connect to my domain controller
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://mybox451Dev.mit.hq.com:389");

        try {

            // Create the initial directory context
            InitialDirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

            //Create a LDAP add attribute for the member attribute
            ModificationItem mods[] = new ModificationItem[1];
            mods[0]= new ModificationItem(DirContext.ADD_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("member", userName)); 

            //update the group
            ctx.modifyAttributes(groupName,mods);

            ctx.close();

            //System.out.println("Added " + userName + " to " + groupName);

        } 

        catch (NamingException e) {
            System.err.println("Problem adding member: " + e);
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

I got it solved. Posting solution here, hope this helps someone.

1. Use the standard JNDI context of sun, not websphere.
2. Additional properties I was missing in the hashtable, once I added them, it worked like a charm.

   ```
   env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");  

   //env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");  

   //set security credentials, note using simple cleartext authentication  
   env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,"simple");  
   env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,adminName);  
   env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,adminPassword);  
   env.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "com.sun.jndi.url");  
   env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "ignore");
   ```

Comment: Which line of code throws that exception?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's been more than a year since this question has been asked; so, I don't know answering will add any value. But, here it is. See [WAS Javadocs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/naming/WsnInitialContextFactory.html) for details on how what that factory class actually does and how it works. You may need to adjust your jndiprovider.properties file for WAS.